# How to Display the index position but +1 in java

Tags: java, arrays

I am needing to display the index of the array but instead of starting at 0 and going through 4. I need it to display 1 and then go through 5. I thought it would be an easy find but i have searched hours and cannot find a resolution for my problem. Ill post my code below.

Comment: Are you asking how to add one to a number, or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: `indexOfTheArray + 1`

Comment: Add  your code along with your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add 1 to your argument in your loop:

```
int[] myArray = new int[5];
for(int x = 0; x < myArray.length; x++){
    System.out.println("Array value at index " + (x + 1) + " is " + myArray[x]);
}
```

Comment: No problem, good luck! Remember to up-vote and accept the answer if it has helped!